# Проблема с обработкой клика по Calendar WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

На форме имеется Calendar, когда в нем выбираю дату, то приходится кликать по любому другому элементу или пустому месту, чтобы остальные элементы стали активны.

То есть после выбора даты, активным остается календарь.
Как от этого избавиться? Чтобы не приходилось делать лишний клик?

В разметке нет ничего особенного:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1">
    <Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"/>
</Border>
```

Получается, когда я нажимаю на него и выбираю дату, то курсор двигается, но остальные элементы неактивны (нет даже анимации при наведении на кнопки). Мне приходится делать "пустой" клик, и тогда остальные элементы начинают отвечать.

Comment: Элементы которые изменяют активность после клика привязаны к командам?

Comment: @Gardes да, например при выборе даты, навожу курсор на кнопку и анимации нет, и нужно сделать 1 клик, и тогда все работает...

Comment: покажите реализацию команды, которая наследуется от ICommand

Comment: @Gardes обновил вопрос

Comment: @Gardes кинул на форму textBox, все равно приходится делать лишний клик

Comment: Похоже на баг контрола, проблема воспроизводится вообще без всяких привязок: достаточно добавить календарь и кнопку. Если мы кликаем что-то в календаре, то клик по кнопке срабатывает только со второго раза

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, так и есть...и вот как с этим бороться?

Comment: Пока не знаю, надо думать.

Comment: А если попробовать DelegateCommand? и вызывать RaiseCanExecuteChanged() вручную?

Comment: @Gardes проблема не в классе команды( даже при наведении на другие элементы ничего не происходит(

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, смотрите ответ. Убрал из вопроса всё неотносящееся к делу.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6024372/6766879

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что `Calendar` предназначен для размещения его во всевозможных всплывающих элементах (например, таких как `DatePicker`), поэтому он захватывает (Capture) мышь. Такое же поведение можно наблюдать, например, с `ComboBox`, если открыть выпадающий список, то первый клик мыши будет закрывать его и только следующий будет обработан целевым элементом.

К счастью, это поведение можно изменить таким кодом:

```
if (Mouse.Captured is CalendarItem) Mouse.Capture(null);
```

Вставьте его, например, в обработчик `PreviewMouseUp` вашего календаря.

Comment: не помогает, подписался на и на MouseUp и MouseDown. Результат тот же...

Comment: Не верю, создайте пустой проект, добавьте в окно Calendar и кнопку и проверьте.

Comment: Создал проект на версии .Net 4.0, добавил MahApps, но app.xaml не менял, добавил код, все равно нужно делать двойной клик...

Comment: извините!!! мой косяк! большое спасибо!!!помогло!

Comment: Ну и хорошо что разобрались :)