# Calendar расширяется при изменении DisplayMode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Проблема с `DisplayMode` календаря. По дефолту всё нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при изменении свойства `DisplayMode` в любое состояние он расширяется за пределы окна и, похоже, вселенной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно вылечить? Пробовал задавать свойство в коде, `maxWidth`, но тоже не спасло.

Comment: в каком контейнере он у вас лежит?

Comment: @Gardes В любом месте такое поведение, пробовал и в StackPanel, и в DockPanel и просто в окно, все одно и то же

Comment: не удается воспроизвести, может скинете разметку?

Comment: @Gardes разметка до жути примитивна) <Calendar DisplayMode="Decade"></Calendar>

Comment: иногда со стороны свежим взглядом удается увидеть проблему под носом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по многочисленным аналогичным вопросам на enSO это или баг, или фича, связанная с тем, что календарь предназначен для размещения во всплывающих элементах, вполне возможно, что контрол календаря создавался только для использования внутри DatePicker и разработчики не предусматривали его самостоятельное использование (см. также этот вопрос: [Проблема с обработкой клика по Calendar WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819560/218063))

В качестве решения — не устанавливайте календарю `DisplayMode` в XAML, а делайте это после загрузки:

```
<Calendar Loaded="Calendar_Loaded"/>
```

и:

```
private void Calendar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Calendar)sender).DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade;
}
```

Comment: И правда, сработало. Я устанавливал DisplayMode по событию загрузки окна и не заводилось. Спасибо!

Comment: Хотя по загрузке окна тоже должно работать (это событие срабатывает, когда загружены все контролы), лучше именно по загрузке контрола. Ну и при желании можно сделать наследника Calendar и реализовать это в нем, чтобы можно было использовать в любом окне или контейнере или шаблоне или др. не задумываясь